# How to stop Install-Package AutoMapper from NuGet - defaulting to client profile?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper, nuget

My project is using AutoMapper, but I've used Nuget to install the package. However, in all my projects under my Mvc solution it is using the client profile .dll. Is there any way to get Nuget to use the correct dll when calling: Install-Package AutoMapper?

Comment: Are you sure that the target fw of your project is correctly set?

Comment: All projects are set to .NET Framework 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the source of the package (rename the package's extension to .zip), it seems that it only contains dll for client and sl4.

[image]

So it's perfectly valid to have a reference to the client version.

You can see all your NuGet packages by exploring the cache:

Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Settings -> Browse

Finaly, you can find more information about [framework version structure](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Framework_Version_Folder_Structure) of a NuGet package from [their website](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/creating-and-publishing-a-package#Framework_Version_Folder_Structure).

Comment: What is sl4? What do you mean rename the extension to.zip?

Comment: sl4 stands for Silverlight 4. A NuGet package has the .nupkg extension that you should change to .zip if you want to see the content.

Comment: yep this is not good, there are 2 folders in the zip file, sl4 and net40-client. My whole project is broken now. Is there any way I can go back to AutoMapper 1 via NuGet?

Comment: Why your project is broken? Yes you can use the -Version argument: Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 1.1.0.118

Comment: I'm getting following error 'Could not load file or assembly 'AutoMapper' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.' even though it is referenced in every project. I thought this was because it was using the wrong framework version?

Comment: Your error should come from somewhere else because client version works without any issue under a .NET 4 application. Verify that the dll has been copied to your bin folder.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5628/discussion-between-stephane-bebrone-and-jaffa)

Comment: You probably need to unblock the package file before using. If you right-click the file and click properties do you see a big "unblock" button?